# Vertically centering H1 within div to match neighbouring div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a h1 heading in a div to appear centered next to the neighbouring div which contains a small image.  Unfortunately,no matter what I try, the h1 always stays at the top of the div.

Here's the html:

```
<header>
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="page-title-icon"></div>
        <div class="page-title"><h1>The heading</h1></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and here's the css

```
.page-header {
  border:0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.page-title-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  background:url(./icons-rollovers.png);
  background-position:-46px -829px;
}

.page-title {
  display: inline-block;
  color:#c82e3d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height:60px;
}

.page-title h1 {
    line-height: 60px;
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `vertical-align: middle;` http://jsfiddle.net/P2Zpc/

Comment: No need for any divs here from what I can see - just posted an alternative answer minus the divs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it not be better to scrap the excess divs and do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <h1>The heading</h1>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header h1 {
    margin:20px 0;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#c82e3d;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-left:60px;
    position:relative;
 }

header h1:before{
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px; 
    background:url(./icons-rollovers.png) left center no-repeat;
    background-position:-46px -829px;   
}
```

[**Slightly simplified JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yGqMN/)

Comment: Nice use of pseudo element, this technique would be especially useful if for come reason you could not alter the original HTML.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the original mark-up is shown in the following CSS:

```
.page-header {
  border:0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.page-title-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);
  background-position:-46px -829px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.page-title {
  display: inline-block;
  color:#c82e3d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height:60px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.page-title h1 {
    line-height: 60px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Apply `vertical-align: top` to the `.page-title-icon` elment to get rid of some extra white space due to line leading.

Apply `margin: 0` to `h1` since the default margins for `h1` are creating extra white space that is throwing off your vertical alignment.

Otherwise, you basically had the answer.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/LmWGm/

**Note:** I added borders to illustrate the edges of the various elements, these can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at his http://jsfiddle.net/naVS2/2/
Hope it helps - the trick is to give the line height 50% of the wrapping div.

```
.page-header {
  border:0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.page-title-icon {
  float:left;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  background:url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png);
    border:solid red;
}

.page-title {
     color: #C82E3D;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

.page-title h1 {
    line-height: 30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a final solution to what you're after, but should get you started off. Try doing something like this instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-title-icon">
        <h1>The heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-header {
    display:inline-block;
}
.page-header .page-title-icon {
    display:inline;
    padding:0 0 0 60px;
    background:url(./icons-rollovers.png);
    background-position:-46px -829px;
}
```